# How to Disable Screen When Using Visual Voicemail?

Tags: screen, voicemail, proximity-sensor

Anyone know of a way to get the screen to automatically turn off when listening to a voicemail? I'm used to the feature of my HTC Evo and HTC Hero, where the proximity sensor automatically detects my face and turns off the screen. This doesn't seem to happen with the visual voicemail app, which is pretty annoying.

On multiple occasions I have accidentally deleted and called the person that left a message for me giving the impression I have fat cheeks. :(

Comment: Same thing happens to my with my Droid when checking my google voice messages.  I think that the proximity only works with the Phone Dialer maybe?

Comment: Man I would love to figure out a workaround for this as having that screen stay on is really annoying.

Comment: You can download "Proximity Sensor" from the market. But app states only works for Hero. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use Tasker to handle the proximity thing.  Additionally have you tried clicking the power button?